# Monodevelop/Xamarin Studio add-in requires a .dll dependency

Tags: xamarin, mono, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I have developed a Monodevelop/Xamarin Studio add-in, and I am ready to publish it. It fails to build on MonoDevelop's Add-in Repository, with a file not found error.  I'm not sure what it's looking for, but it does raise the question about dependencies.  I'm using Renci.SshNet.dll.  Do I include that in my github repository?  And do I make reference to it in my addin-project.xml file?

Comment: Are you using mhutch's MonoDevelop.AddinMaker?

Comment: @FlappySocks, provide a link to the repository so we can have a look at the setup and make sure everything is correct.

Comment: The plugin is here https://github.com/logicethos/SSHDebugger

Answer (score 0):

Within your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, add an `ImportAddinAssembly` attribute to specify the addin has a dependency on `Renci.SshNet.dll`:

```
[assembly:Mono.Addins.ImportAddinAssembly("Renci.SshNet.dll")]
```

Comment: That alone was not enough to get the build process to complete.  See my add-in project here https://github.com/logicethos/SSHDebugger

Comment: Ok, I would start by removing the dependency 'AddinFile' nodes from the 'addin-project.xml'; to my knowledge you only need an `AddinFile` node for the build output assembly not the dependencies. You've already specified they are a dependency in the manifest.